# How to make up/down buttons appear/disappear on a vertical slider?

Tags: jquery

I have a vertical slider with images and two buttons(slide up and down). I managed to make them disappear but I can't make reaper when they should. The jsfiddle should be self explanatory. Any advices is welcome.

```
function set(scrolled){
var scrolle = scrolled;
if(scrolle<1){
    $('.up').hide();
}else if(scrolle>=400){
    $('.down').hide();
}else if(scrolle > 10){
    $('.up').show();
}else if(scrolle<400){
    $('.down').show();        
}
```

}

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1caytuf0/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, you need to change in your code this:

```
else if(scrolle > 10){
    $('.up').show();
```

to this, by just adding `.down` to show, like this:

```
else if(scrolle > 10){
    $('.up, .down').show();
```

Check snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scrolled = 0;
    $('.up').hide();
    $(".down").on("click", function () {
        scrolled = scrolled + 50;
        console.log(scrolled);
        set(scrolled);
        $("#container").animate({
            scrollTop: scrolled
        });
    });

    $(".up").on("click", function () {
        scrolled = scrolled - 50;
        console.log(scrolled);
        set(scrolled);
        $("#container").animate({
            scrollTop: scrolled
        });
    });

    function set(scrolled) {
        var scrolle = scrolled;
        if (scrolle < 1) {
            $('.up').hide();
        } else if (scrolle >= 400) {
            $('.down').hide();
        } else if (scrolle > 10) {
            $('.up, .down').show();
        } else if (scrolle < 400) {
            $('.down').show();
        }
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
    border:solid 1px red;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.cent {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="cent">
    <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img id="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img id="image3_small" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
    <img id="image4" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img id="image5" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img id="image6" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
    <img id="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img id="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img id="image3_small" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
    <img id="image4" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img id="image5" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img id="image6" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
    <img id="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img id="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img id="image3_small" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
    <img id="image4" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img id="image5" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img id="image6" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
    <img id="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img id="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img id="image3_small" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
    <img id="image4" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img id="image5" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img id="image6" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
    <img id="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img id="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img id="image3_small" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
    <img id="image4" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img id="image5" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/100/50/city/1/">
</div>
<button class="up">UP</button>
<button class="down">Down</button>
```